# Get county/city/state from user current location

Tags: html, google-maps

I am building a new page in the website where i need to access user County/City/State information based on where the user is accessing the page from. Application uses Html5, can this be achieved using google maps api or any other, if so can you please provide some pointers on where there are sample implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the geolocation example in the Google Maps JavaScript API documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

You should just add reverse geocoding to get city, state and country. The following code snippet should do the trick

```js
var map, infoWindow;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 6
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            
            geocoder.geocode({'location': pos}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
              if (results[0]) {
                var filtered_array = results[0].address_components.filter(function(address_component){
                  return address_component.types.includes("country");
                }); 
                var country = filtered_array.length ? filtered_array[0].long_name: "";
                filtered_array = results[0].address_components.filter(function(address_component){
                  return address_component.types.includes("locality");
                }); 
                var locality = filtered_array.length ? filtered_array[0].long_name: "";
                filtered_array = results[0].address_components.filter(function(address_component){
                  return address_component.types.includes("administrative_area_level_1");
                }); 
                var admin_area = filtered_array.length ? filtered_array[0].long_name: "";
                
                
                infoWindow.setContent('Location found.<br/>City:'+locality+'<br/>State:'+admin_area+'<br/>Country:'+country);
                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                infoWindow.open(map);
                map.setCenter(pos);
              } else {
                window.alert('No results found');
              }
            } else {
              window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
            });   
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
```

```css
#map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: @Easton James Harvey County is typically administrative area level 2, so you can apply the same technique to get it.